# How can I open a Superfish jQuery Menu on click rather than hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, superfish

I've had a quick browse around the web for an implementation of Superfish menu by Joel Birch that works on onclick, rather than hover.

Found this link by Karl Swedberg at Github, which looks like the ticket.

https://gist.github.com/917446

It works like a charm, right up to the point where I click on an active link, at that point the menu closes, and appears to return false.

How can I get it to navigate to the actual link destination?

Comment: Paul, please accept your answer to resolve the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing this line (line 21, over function):

```
$$.showSuperfishUl().siblings().hideSuperfishUl();
```

To this:

```
$$.click(function(){$(this).showSuperfishUl().siblings().hideSuperfishUl();});
```

Full superfish code for clicking the menu:

```
/*
 * Superfish v1.4.8 - jQuery menu widget
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * CHANGELOG: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/changelog.txt
 */

;(function($){
    $.fn.superfish = function(op){

        var sf = $.fn.superfish,
            c = sf.c,
            $arrow = $(['<span class="',c.arrowClass,'"> &#187;</span>'].join('')),
            over = function(){
                var $$ = $(this), menu = getMenu($$);
                clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);
                $$.click(function(){$(this).showSuperfishUl().siblings().hideSuperfishUl();});
            },
            out = function(){
                var $$ = $(this), menu = getMenu($$), o = sf.op;
                clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);
                menu.sfTimer=setTimeout(function(){
                    o.retainPath=($.inArray($$[0],o.$path)>-1);
                    $$.hideSuperfishUl();
                    if (o.$path.length && $$.parents(['li.',o.hoverClass].join('')).length<1){over.call(o.$path);}
                },o.delay); 
            },
            getMenu = function($menu){
                var menu = $menu.parents(['ul.',c.menuClass,':first'].join(''))[0];
                sf.op = sf.o[menu.serial];
                return menu;
            },
            addArrow = function($a){ $a.addClass(c.anchorClass).append($arrow.clone()); };

        return this.each(function() {
            var s = this.serial = sf.o.length;
            var o = $.extend({},sf.defaults,op);
            o.$path = $('li.'+o.pathClass,this).slice(0,o.pathLevels).each(function(){
                $(this).addClass([o.hoverClass,c.bcClass].join(' '))
                    .filter('li:has(ul)').removeClass(o.pathClass);
            });
            sf.o[s] = sf.op = o;

            $('li:has(ul)',this)[($.fn.hoverIntent && !o.disableHI) ? 'hoverIntent' : 'hover'](over,out).each(function() {
                if (o.autoArrows) addArrow( $('>a:first-child',this) );
            })
            .not('.'+c.bcClass)
                .hideSuperfishUl();

            var $a = $('a',this);
            $a.each(function(i){
                var $li = $a.eq(i).parents('li');
                $a.eq(i).focus(function(){over.call($li);}).blur(function(){out.call($li);});
            });
            o.onInit.call(this);

        }).each(function() {
            var menuClasses = [c.menuClass];
            if (sf.op.dropShadows  && !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7)) menuClasses.push(c.shadowClass);
            $(this).addClass(menuClasses.join(' '));
        });
    };

    var sf = $.fn.superfish;
    sf.o = [];
    sf.op = {};
    sf.IE7fix = function(){
        var o = sf.op;
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 6 && o.dropShadows && o.animation.opacity!=undefined)
            this.toggleClass(sf.c.shadowClass+'-off');
        };
    sf.c = {
        bcClass     : 'sf-breadcrumb',
        menuClass   : 'sf-js-enabled',
        anchorClass : 'sf-with-ul',
        arrowClass  : 'sf-sub-indicator',
        shadowClass : 'sf-shadow'
    };
    sf.defaults = {
        hoverClass  : 'sfHover',
        pathClass   : 'overideThisToUse',
        pathLevels  : 1,
        delay       : 200,
        animation   : {opacity:'show'},
        speed       : 'fast',
        autoArrows  : true,
        dropShadows : true,
        disableHI   : false,        // true disables hoverIntent detection
        onInit      : function(){}, // callback functions
        onBeforeShow: function(){},
        onShow      : function(){},
        onHide      : function(){}
    };
    $.fn.extend({
        hideSuperfishUl : function(){
            var o = sf.op,
                not = (o.retainPath===true) ? o.$path : '';
            o.retainPath = false;
            var $ul = $(['li.',o.hoverClass].join(''),this).add(this).not(not).removeClass(o.hoverClass)
                    .find('>ul').hide().css('visibility','hidden');
            o.onHide.call($ul);
            return this;
        },
        showSuperfishUl : function(){
            var o = sf.op,
                sh = sf.c.shadowClass+'-off',
                $ul = this.addClass(o.hoverClass)
                    .find('>ul:hidden').css('visibility','visible');
            sf.IE7fix.call($ul);
            o.onBeforeShow.call($ul);
            $ul.animate(o.animation,o.speed,function(){ sf.IE7fix.call($ul); o.onShow.call($ul); });
            return this;
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 8):

Karl posted a quick update to help me out on GitHub.. here: https://gist.github.com/652684 that didn't quite work for me.

Grab my working code from the below link.

http://www.nilinks.com/home-owner/wp-content/themes/acheson/js/superfish.js

updated.. just incase that link ever dies..

```
/*
 * Superfish v1.4.8 - jQuery menu widget
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Joel Birch
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * CHANGELOG: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/changelog.txt
 */

;(function($){
    $.fn.superfish = function(op){

        var sf = $.fn.superfish,
            c = sf.c,
            $arrow = $(['<span class="',c.arrowClass,'"> &#187;</span>'].join('')),
            over = function(){
                var $this = $(this), menu = getMenu($this);
                clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);
                $this.showSuperfishUl().siblings().hideSuperfishUl();
            },
            out = function(){
                var $this = $(this), menu = getMenu($this), o = sf.op;
                clearTimeout(menu.sfTimer);
                menu.sfTimer=setTimeout(function(){
                    o.retainPath=($.inArray($this[0],o.$path)>-1);
                    $this.hideSuperfishUl();
                    if (o.$path.length && $this.parents(['li.',o.hoverClass].join('')).length<1){over.call(o.$path);}
                },o.delay); 
            },
            getMenu = function($menu){
                var menu = $menu.parents(['ul.',c.menuClass,':first'].join(''))[0];
                sf.op = sf.o[menu.serial];
                return menu;
            },
            addArrow = function($a){ $a.addClass(c.anchorClass).append($arrow.clone()); };

        return this.each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
            var s = this.serial = sf.o.length;
            var o = $.extend({},sf.defaults,op);
            o.$path = $('li.'+o.pathClass,this).slice(0,o.pathLevels).each(function(){
                $(this).addClass([o.hoverClass,c.bcClass].join(' '))
                    .filter('li:has(ul)').removeClass(o.pathClass);
            });
            sf.o[s] = sf.op = o;
      // CHANGED: by KARL SWEDBERG
            if ( (o.eventType === 'hoverIntent' && !$.fn.hoverIntent) || !(/^(?:hover|hoverIntent|toggle)$/).test(o.eventType) ) {
              o.eventType = 'hover';
            }
            $this.find('li:has(ul)')[o.eventType](over,out).each(function() {
                if (o.autoArrows) {
                  addArrow( $('>a:first-child',this) );
                 // this.addClass("yourClass");
                }
            })
            .not('.'+c.bcClass)
                .hideSuperfishUl();


            $this.find('a').each(function(i){
                var $a = $(this), $li = $a.parents('li');
                $a.focus(function(){over.call($li);}).blur(function(){out.call($li);});
                $a.click(function(event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  if ( !$a.hasClass("sf-with-ul") ) {
                    location.href = this.href;
                  }
                });
            });
            o.onInit.call(this);

        }).each(function() {
            var menuClasses = [c.menuClass];
            if (sf.op.dropShadows  && !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7)) {
              menuClasses.push(c.shadowClass);
            }
            $(this).addClass(menuClasses.join(' '));
        });
    };

    var sf = $.fn.superfish;
    sf.o = [];
    sf.op = {};
    sf.IE7fix = function(){
        var o = sf.op;
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version > 6 && o.dropShadows && o.animation.opacity!=undefined) {
            this.toggleClass(sf.c.shadowClass+'-off');
        }
        };
    sf.c = {
        bcClass     : 'sf-breadcrumb',
        menuClass   : 'sf-js-enabled',
        anchorClass : 'sf-with-ul',
        arrowClass  : 'sf-sub-indicator',
        shadowClass : 'sf-shadow'
    };
    sf.defaults = {
        hoverClass  : 'sfHover',
        pathClass   : 'overideThisToUse',
        pathLevels  : 1,
        delay       : 800,
        animation   : {opacity:'show'},     
        speed       : 'normal',
        closeAnimation: {opacity: 'hide'},
        closeSpeed: 0,
        autoArrows  : true,
        dropShadows : true,
    // CHANGED: by KARL SWEDBERG
        eventType   : 'toggle', // one of 'toggle', 'hover', or 'hoverIntent'
    // disableHI  : false,    // true disables hoverIntent detection
        onInit      : function(){}, // callback functions
        onBeforeShow: function(){},
        onShow      : function(){},
        onHide      : function(){}
    };
    $.fn.extend({
        hideSuperfishUl : function(){
            var o = sf.op,
                not = (o.retainPath===true) ? o.$path : '';
            o.retainPath = false;
            var $closingLi = $(['li.',o.hoverClass].join(''),this).add(this).not(not);
            var $ul = $closingLi
                    .find('>ul');
            $ul.animate(o.closeAnimation, o.closeSpeed, function() {
              $closingLi.removeClass(o.hoverClass);
        $ul.css('visibility','hidden');
      });
            o.onHide.call($ul);
            return this;
        },
        showSuperfishUl : function(){
            var o = sf.op,
                sh = sf.c.shadowClass+'-off',
                $ul = this.addClass(o.hoverClass)
                    .find('>ul:hidden').css('visibility','visible');
            sf.IE7fix.call($ul);
            o.onBeforeShow.call($ul);
            $ul.animate(o.animation,o.speed,function(){ sf.IE7fix.call($ul); o.onShow.call($ul); });
            return this;
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Just wondering why is the line `location.href = this.href` neccesary, I'm trying to make it work without it with no luck. That is to say, why is it being lost the deault action of the <a> tag? Could you please explain?

Comment: location.href = current window. this.href = a tag href.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes here looking for this answer while using the superfish module in drupal (I am using the drupal 8 module). I didn't modify the superfish library at all. I did the following is in my js file and it seems to be working fine (tested on chrome and firefox).

The below code disables the menu dropping down on mouseover. When you click the parent menu item the menu drops down and does not actually go to the parent href.

```
$('#superfish-main > li > a.menuparent').on('mouseover click', function(event) {
  return false;
});
```

I dont use superfish as my mobile menu so I have not tested the above on mobile, but I'd imagine you'll need to do some work to get it how you want it.

**EDIT**

The above wasn't working on safari for some reason. The below works on chrome, safari and firefox

```
$('#superfish-main > li > a').on('mouseover', function(event) {
  return false;
});
$('#superfish-main > li > a.menuparent').on('click', function(event) {
  // Close any open dropdown menus.
  $.each($(this), function(index, element) {
    $(element).parent().parent().find('li.menuparent > ul').addClass('sf-hidden');
  });
  // Open the clicked dropdown menu.
  $(this).next().removeClass('sf-hidden');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```