# Replace superfish hover event with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, superfish

I have used superfish module for more style of my site. It is working fine but I want to remove the mouseover effect from main menu link.
I want to just display the child menu link after clicking the main menu.

My site link is http://devel.studiesweekly.com

when you hover the mouse in main red button menu link it is showing immidiately the child menu bar bellow. I want to show only after click the main menus.

How can I do this? I have used drupal 7.x

Answer (score 1):

You can change the event from the superfish library from `hover` to `click`.

Replace your current superfish library code with the code provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7489778/863380).