# Show Superfish dropdown menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use bootstrap 3 and I have menu. Also I use `superfish.js` for menu. It works but it shows dropdown menu on hover,
but I want to show dropdown menu on click.

My html:

```
<div id="navbar-collapse-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul id="menu-testing-menu" class="nav navbar-nav sf-js-enabled" style="touch-action: pan-y;">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children dropdown">
            <a class="sf-with-ul" data-toggle="dropdown">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipdum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipdum</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Lorem Ipdum</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My js:

```
$("#menu-testing-menu").superfish({
    delay: 100,
    animation: {
        opacity: 'show',
        height: 'show'
    },
    speed: 'normal',
    cssArrows: false
});
```

My css:

```
li.menu-item.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

So is it possible to show dropdown menu on click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Superfish jQuery Menu, open on click rather than hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312414/superfish-jquery-menu-open-on-click-rather-than-hover)

Comment: This isn't a Bootstrap question. Superfish doesn't have an event option, so you'd have to hack it up.

Comment: May be this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312414/how-can-i-open-a-superfish-jquery-menu-on-click-rather-than-hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superfish  doesn't offer this option: it is intented right to open/close menu on hover in/out.
In order to open/show dropdown with  a click you can:

- disable ([stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)): mouseenter mouseout
- [show/hide](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) menu on click

```js
$("#menu-testing-menu").superfish({
    delay: 100,
    animation: {
        opacity: 'show',
        height: 'show'
    },
    speed: 'normal',
    cssArrows: false
});
$('.sf-with-ul').on('mouseenter mouseout', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
$('.sf-with-ul').on('click', function (e) {
    $(".dropdown-menu").toggle(!$(".dropdown-menu").is(':visible'));
})
```

Comment: below code is enough, thanks.

  $('.sf-with-ul').on('mouseenter mouseout', function(e) {

      e.stopPropagation();

    });