# Check if element has style and add or remove jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have like this **HTML**

```
<li class="megamenu-less">
    <a href="#" class="home-link sf-with-ul">Menu</a>
    <ul class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When i hover on **li.megamenu-less** I just on **.dropdown** says display:block, that way my menu works on hover to show dropdown, but i need something else.

I need to that on click on **.megamenu-less** and then show dropdown, but the problem is that i have a lot of element in menu and i need only for that dropdown to change css, also i need to check if the menu is opened and and on click to say block or none based is it opened

I have used some sf-menu that work that way now i need to override it :(

Comment: you can use [`is(':visible')`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and that will tell you if it is block or none or just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) if you just want to make it the opposite state

Comment: I am using some sf-fish menu, i can not to simple like that i need to make another function to override,

Comment: Useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312414/how-can-i-open-a-superfish-jquery-menu-on-click-rather-than-hover

Comment: $(".megamenu-less").click(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.dropdown').css('display') == 'block') {
            $(this).find('.dropdown').css({ 'display': "none" });
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

In order to open/show dropdown with a click you can:

1. disable (stopPropagation): mouseenter mouseout
2. show/hide menu on click

> ```
> $("#yourmenu").superfish({
>     delay: 100,
>     animation: {
>         opacity: 'show',
>         height: 'show'
>     },
>     speed: 'normal',
>     cssArrows: false
> });
> $('.sf-with-ul').on('mouseenter mouseout', function(e) {
>     e.stopPropagation();
> })
> $('.sf-with-ul').on('click', function (e) {
>     $(".dropdown").toggle(!$(".dropdown").is(':visible'));
> })
> ```